# Spring boot with apache OpenJPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, openjpa, spring-orm

I am trying to integrate my test spring boot application with DB. 
I don't want to use Hibernate vendor, **I want to use apache OpenJPA.**

My current bootstrap.yml looks like this

```
spring:
    datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:1521:xxx
    username: xxxx
    password: xxxx
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

1. Is it possible to set dialect to work with OpenJPA?
2. Does spring supports today OpenJpa?

If you could provide some example of configuration it would be great.

Thank in advance.

**upd:** In example founded here - [configure openjpa on to spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928001/configure-openjpa-on-to-spring-boot) I see that used OpenJpaVendorAdapter which does not exist in spring 5.

In documentation of spring-data https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ said that

> Spring Data JPA 1.10 added the following features:
>   Upgrade to Querydsl 4, Hibernate 5, **OpenJPA 2.4**, and EclipseLink 2.6.1.

However I still don't see the proper way to configure it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [configure openjpa on to spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928001/configure-openjpa-on-to-spring-boot)

Comment: Question was how could I do it with yml config, and also does spring supports that. Don't think it is duplicate

Comment: (a) Spring 5 [does not support OpenJPA](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18997) as Spring 5 targets JPA 2.1, which OpenJPA did not support at the time Spring 5 was released. (b) Spring Boot is [highly opinionated](http://spring.io/projects/spring-boot), and [only supports Hibernate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter) out-of-the-box. In short, there is no off-the-shelf option for integrating OpenJPA with Spring 5. If required, one can take the code from the Spring 4 code base and write their own adapter.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. Thanks

Comment: @liotur any update for this thread. i also need to implement openjpa

Comment: I did as advised by @manish. Copied few classes from spring 4, and created my custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20584) page, You can not use Open Jpa with spring 5.
But this is an example for spring 4.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.baoviet.mhol.persistence.dao")
@ComponentScan("com.baoviet.mhol.service")
public class JpaConfig {
    @Bean(destroyMethod ="" )
    public DataSource dataSource(@Value("${db.jndi}") String jndiName) {
        JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        lookup.setResourceRef(true);
        return lookup.getDataSource(jndiName);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("com.baoviet.mhol.persistence.model");
        lef.setJpaDialect(new OpenJpaDialect());
        return lef;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        OpenJpaVendorAdapter OpenJpaVendorAdaptor = new OpenJpaVendorAdapter();
        OpenJpaVendorAdaptor.setShowSql(true);
        OpenJpaVendorAdaptor.setGenerateDdl(true);
        OpenJpaVendorAdaptor.setDatabasePlatform("org.OpenJpa.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        return OpenJpaVendorAdaptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    }
}
```

Remember, in this case You do not need to persistence.xml file.

And This is Application.properties.

```
db.jndi=jdbc/batch
```

Note:
OpenJpa needs Persistence.xml to enhance entities at compile time.
So, You need to use different method for entity enhancement or provide your metadata in xml other than persistence.xml or use persistence.xml instead of data source.
You need to search for these more.
for entity enhancement solutions, please visit [hear](https://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/2.2.x/docbook/ref_guide_pc_enhance.html)